# How to get the size of std::vector <DMatch>

Tags: c++, image-processing, vector

I am doing image stiching and I have the next problem.

```
 BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING, true);
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
cout<< "descr " << descriptors_1.rows << endl ;
  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
  {

      double dist = matches[i].distance;

  //cout<<"La distancia es " << i<<endl;
    if( dist < min_dist && dist >3)
        {

            min_dist = dist;
        }
    if( dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
  }
```

I call for a Matcher, in this case a BruteForce Matcher, and when I am obtaining the minimun and maximun distance between keypoints, the program crashes. I know that the problem is in

```
matches[i].distance;
```

Because I thing that this object is NULL. The problem is that I don't know how can I check if matches[i] exists or not exists.

Comment: If you want to get the size, are you able to use some of the vectors function? Like size() you can also check in an if statement if the object exist or not.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, BFMatcher::match() inserts matches to its 3rd argument (a std::vector), as the number of rows in its 1st and 2nd arguments (equal number of rows, I hope).

In that case, your guess is probably not the cause of the crash.

Anyway, to get the size of the vector : matches.size() will give you the number of DMatch objects stored in your vector.